# How can I filter a JSON data in Node.js using Axios?

Tags: node.js, json, rest, filter, axios

I'm newbie Back-end developer and I'm trying to build a REST API with Node.js to get the deals won from Pipedrive. I already have a function to get all deals using Axios, and it is working just fine, but I need to filter its response to send me just the ones with "won" status. I've created some deals in the Pipedrive with different status, like "won", "lost", and "open". I had a function "getAllDeals" that send me all those ones in JSON. I tried to adapt it in many different ways with no success.

I call this function in my route /deals:

```
router.get('/deals', controller.getAllDeals)
```

This is my function, which is working, to get all the deals:

```
 async getAllDeals(_, res){

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${PIPE_URL}?api_token=${PIPE_TOKEN}`)
            return res.json(response.data)
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

And this one is my last try to filter its response data:

```
async getAllDeals(_, res){

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${PIPE_URL}?api_token=${PIPE_TOKEN}`)
            const deals = res.json(response.data)
            const dealsWon = response.where(deals, {status: "won"})
            return dealsWon
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

I hope there is a simple way to do it.

Comment: check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` for filtering your deals based on what you need. Something like this should work.

```js
const dealsWon = deals.filter(deal => deal.status === "won")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's `response.where`. You can use `lodash.where` module to help you with this. depends on the response structure, you can use `lodash.where` to extract the relevant data you need. So your code should like this:

```
const where = require("lodash.where");

async getAllDeals(_, res){

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${PIPE_URL}?api_token=${PIPE_TOKEN}`)
        const deals = res.json(response.data)
        const dealsWon = where(deals, {status: "won"})
        return dealsWon
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

of course don't forget to install the module `npm i lodash.where`

Answer (score 0):

I've read on Pipedrive documentation that the satus is a query parameter, and it will filter Deals by the provided specific status: `?open=Open`, `?won=Won`, `?lost=Lost`.

I insert the query in my axios request this way:

```
const response = await axios.get(`${PIPE_URL}?status=Won&api_token=${PIPE_TOKEN}`)
```

After I did that, my requests only returned the deals with "won" status.